# How to concatenate n rows side-by-side in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I want to combine the five rows of the same dataset into a single dataset
I have 700 rows and I want to combine every five rows:

```
      A  B  C  D  E  F   G
1     10,11,12,13,14,15,16    
2     17,18,19,20,21,22,23    
3     24,25,26,27,28,29,30      
4     31,32,33,34,35,36,37    
5     38,39,40,41,42,43,44
.
.
.
.
.
700
```

After combining the first five rows.. My first row should look like this:

```
        A  B  C  D  E  F  G  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  A  B  C  D  E  F  G
                                                                         
    1  10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44
```

Comment: so for the next five rows there will be a separate row in your result df?

Comment: Yes exactly  @SomeDude

Comment: i've updated my answer to match your Edit @bigci10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the total number of rows you have is a multiple of 5, dipping into `numpy` will be the most efficient way to solve this problem:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.arange(70).reshape(-1, 7)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[*'ABCDEFG'])

print(df)
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   7   8   9  10  11  12  13
2  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
3  21  22  23  24  25  26  27
4  28  29  30  31  32  33  34
5  35  36  37  38  39  40  41
6  42  43  44  45  46  47  48
7  49  50  51  52  53  54  55
8  56  57  58  59  60  61  62
9  63  64  65  66  67  68  69

out = pd.DataFrame(
    df.to_numpy().reshape(-1, df.shape[1] * 5),
    columns=[*df.columns] * 5
)

print(out)
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   A   B   C   D   E   F  ...   B   C   D   E   F   G   A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  ...  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34
1  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  ...  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69

[2 rows x 35 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to convert your dataframe to a numpy array, reshape it then cast it back to a new dataframe.

Edit:

```
data= # your dataframe
new_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(data.to_numpy().reshape(len(data)//5,-1),columns=np.tile(data.columns,5))
```

Comment: I need for my all rows. I have 700 rows and i want to combining every five rows

Comment: please edit your question with more details

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
cols = [col for v in [df.columns.tolist()]*len(df) for col in v]
dfs = [df[i:min(i+5,len(df))].reset_index(drop=True) for i in range(0,len(df),5)]
df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df.stack()).T for df in dfs])
df2.columns = cols
df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I have a lot of rows

Comment: @bigci10 you need to clearly state your problem in your description

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `arange()` with `floordiv` to get groups by every 5, then creating a new `df` with the groups. This should work even if your `df` is not divisible by 5.

```
l = 5
(df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index))//l)
 .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame([x.to_numpy().ravel()]))
 .set_axis(df.columns.tolist() * l,axis=1)
 .reset_index(drop=True))
```

or

```
(df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index))//5)
.apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True).stack())
.unstack(level=[1,2])
.droplevel(0,axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  A  B  C  ...  E  F  G  A  B  C  D  E  F  G
0  9  0  3  2  6  2  9  1  7  5  ...  2  5  9  5  4  9  7  3  8  9
1  9  5  0  8  1  5  8  7  7  7  ...  6  3  5  5  2  3  9  7  5  6
```

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps answer your question
unstack turns the columns into rows, and once we have the data in a column, we just need it transposed. reset_index makes the resulting series into a dataframe. the original columns names are made into an index, so when we transpose we have the columns as you had stated in your columns.

```
df.unstack().reset_index().set_index('level_0')[[0]].T
```

```
level_0 A   A   A   A   A   B   B   B   B   B   ... F   F   F   F   F   G   G   G   G   G
0   10  17  24  31  38  11  18  25  32  39  ... 15  22  29  36  43  16  23  30  37  44
```

vote and/or accept if the answer helps

Answer (score 0):

### Stacking and unstacking data in pandas

Data in tables are often presented multiple ways. Long form ("tidy data") refers to data that are stacked in a couple of columns. One of the columns will have categorical indicators about the values. In contrast, wide form ("stacked data") is where each category has it's own column.

In your example, you present the wide form of data, and you're trying to get it into long form. The pandas.melt, pandas.groupby, pandas.pivot, pandas.stack, pandas.unstack, and pandas.reset_index are the functions that help convert between these forms.

**Start with your original dataframe:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'A' : [10, 17, 24, 31, 38],
   'B' : [11, 18, 25, 32, 39],
   'C' : [12, 19, 26, 33, 40],
   'D' : [13, 20, 27, 34, 41],
   'E' : [14, 21, 28, 35, 42],
   'F' : [15, 22, 29, 36, 43],
   'G' : [16, 23, 30, 37, 44]})

    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
1   17  18  19  20  21  22  23
2   24  25  26  27  28  29  30
3   31  32  33  34  35  36  37
4   38  39  40  41  42  43  44
```

**Use pandas.melt to convert it to long form, then sort to get it how you requested the data:** The ignore index option helps us to get it back to wide form later.

```
melted_df = df.melt(ignore_index=False).sort_values(by='value')


variable    value
0   A   10
0   B   11
0   C   12
0   D   13
0   E   14
0   F   15
0   G   16
1   A   17
1   B   18
...
```

**Use groupby, unstack, and reset_index to convert it back to wide form.** This is often a much more difficult process that relies on grouping by the value stacked column, other columns, index, and stacked variable and then unstacking and resetting the index.

```
(melted_df
    .reset_index() # puts the index values into a column called 'index'
    .groupby(['index','variable']) #groups by the index and the variable
    .value  #selects the value column in each of the groupby objects
    .mean() #since there is only one item per group, it only aggregates one item
    .unstack() #this sets the first item of the multi-index to columns
    .reset_index() #fix the index
    .set_index('index') #set index
)
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G                           
0   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
1   17  18  19  20  21  22  23
2   24  25  26  27  28  29  30
3   31  32  33  34  35  36  37
4   38  39  40  41  42  43  44
```

This stuff can be quite difficult and requires trial and error. I would recommend making a smaller version of your problems and mess with them. This way you can figure out how the functions are working.